# Wordpress wp-admin getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I have updated my WordPress blog. I am opening this site through IP Address. Everything working fine even front-end looking good. But when I am trying to opening `wp-admin` I am getting this error message-

```
403 Forbidden
Access is forbidden to the requested page:
185.2.4.22/~kw1j5xkt/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F185.2.4.22%2F%7Ekw1j5xkt%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 (port 80)
```

Blog- http://185.2.4.22/~kw1j5xkt/blog

Blog Admin - http://185.2.4.22/~kw1j5xkt/blog/wp-admin

let me know What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Any plugin are you using for security? Also what permission you have set for wp-admin and wp-content folders?

Comment: Also share your .Htaccess file code please.

Comment: This might be related to htaccess, because login page is directly accessible: http://185.2.4.22/~kw1j5xkt/blog/wp-login.php

. Also try to add "Options +FollowSymLinks"  to you htaccess.

Comment: @Nikhil - Yeah I was thinking same:)

Answer (score 0):

Delete any security plugin and remove all code from your `.htacces` and the paste the bellow code

`.htaccess` would totally block everyone from seeing your site. It's denying access from everyone.

**A normal .htaccess has this:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```